# 40K: strategies to help my Ork Trukks/Battlewagons survive long enough to deliver their passengers into assault range?

Tags: warhammer-40k, orks

I have an armored infantry style 40K Ork army: Nobz/Boyz/Burnaboyz in Trukks and Battlewagons. Against an army with any sort of shooty capability, I rarely can get the troops into assault range. Their transports get blown up, and then it's a long walk whilst getting shot up.

If this army style just can't work, that's fine. I am wondering what sort of strategy, if any, would assist my transports getting the troops into assault range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to get Battlewagons across the board, that I've see used, is to attach a Big Mek with a Kustom Force Field to the squad inside.

This will make the Battlewagon(and I think every other vehicle within 6 inches of the Battlewagon) obscured.  A 4+ cover save should help you get across the board a little more consistently.